# Notepad++ can't open files sepearately for python

Tags: python, notepad++

I have recently started using notepad++ for my coding in various different programming languages. In Python specifically, I have tried to open a basic text file (.txt), and print the text inside the file. If I run this file via just double clicking it (in Windows Explorer, not in Notepad++), it will run,  and do exactly what I want it to do; print the contents of the text file. However, if I try and run it directly from Notepad++ with the line

```
C:\Python25\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

then it comes up with an error telling me 'it cannot find the file specified'.

I am under the suspicion that it is using its own directory to try and find the files, so if that is the case is it possible to change it to the files directory?

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Python25\python.exe` probably isnt **your** path to python ... I think you just copied it from somewhere

you should probably put the path to **your** python installation instead (I would guess its something like `C:\Python27\python.exe`

Comment: No because I have Python 2.5 installed, and it cannot open my text file in the same directory as my python code. If I try running a file which simply 'print("hello")' that works perfectly.

Comment: then post the actual code that has the error as well as the full traceback ... the part of the code you put is not the issue ... try `print os.getcwd()` instead of `print "hello"` .... if you are using python 2.5 you probably should not be using `print("hello")` ...

Comment: I did try 'print os.getcwd()', but It comes back with an error, I believe which states 'getcwd' is not an attribute of os. As to your second point, It doesn't make a difference if I hve brackets round the statement I wish to print. And finally, I would give you my error message, but the window closes too quickly, and of course if I used IDLE to copy and paste my error message, then there would be no error anyway, as it is only with Notepad++ that the error occurs. However, I fixed the problem with an addon, so I no longer need help, but thankyou anyway.